# How to explicitly import 'Fn' pattern from Test.QuickCheck?

Tags: haskell, quickcheck, pattern-synonyms

Haskell's [`Test.QuickCheck`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck-2.14.2/docs/Test-QuickCheck.html) module exports `pattern Fn`, which I have been using.

When I import it with:

```
import Test.QuickCheck
```

it works fine. However, when I import it with:

```
import Test.QuickCheck (Fn)
```

I get an error: `Module ‘Test.QuickCheck’ does not export ‘Fn’`. I have also tried `import Test.QuickCheck (Fun(Fn))`, but get a similar error doing that.

As mentioned, the blanket import works, but here my preference is to use explicit imports so that I can easily see where each imported term came from. Is it possible to import such 'patterns' explicitly?

Comment: Try writing `import Test.QuickCheck (pattern Fn)`.

Comment: @Iceland_jack thanks but that gives an error again, this time "error: parse error on input ‘Fn’"

Comment: @Iceland_jack ah, looks like your suggestion along with {-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-} (as in leftaroundabout's answer) will do it. Thanks!

Comment: Ah yes I forget which extensions are needed, I'm glad @leftaroundabout had the complete answer. Fun fact, I added Fn!

Comment: Wow you added Fn, awesome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do `import Test.QuickCheck (Fun(Fn))` because, although `Fn` does construct a `Fun` value, it is not actually one of the associated constructors of this type. Rather, it is a standalone pattern synonym. As such, you need the corresponding extension to explicitly import it:

```
{-# LANGUAGE PatternSynonyms #-}
import Test.QuickCheck (pattern Fn)
```